# Problem with custom Jquery function (show/hide)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showhideitems(itemID){
      if ($(itemID).css('display') == 'none')
      {
        $(itemID).show('slow'); 
      } else { 
        $(itemID).hide('slow');
      } 
    }
});
</script>
```

When I call the function using:

```
`<a href="#" onClick="showhideitems('#players1')">`
```

It doesn't work (the div doesn't show/hide). What is wrong with the above function?

Comment: @KeokiZee My problem is that by doing:
$('#target').click( function... );
I cannot pass different variables to my function (I have different IDs to pass according to the link)

Comment: you can use the jQuery version. See me answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something more flexible

I would add a data attribute to the a tag, describing which elements to manipulate. The attribute value can include any valid jQuery selector.

```
<a href="#" data-hide="#players1">Click me</a>
```

The the JavaScript will listen for click events on all tags with the data-hide attribute.

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-hide]').live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var targetEl = $(this).attr('data-hide');
        $(targetEl).toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

See an example h[ttp://jsfiddle.net/emil/8xtpf/](http://jsfiddle.net/emil/8xtpf/)

The good thing about this approach is that you can reuse the function to hide different elements, triggered by different anchors. All you need to do it add the data-hide attribute.

Comment: Excellent! More compact than the other solutions and more flexible as you said. Works fine!

Answer (score 4):

Put the function outside of ready(). The method you are trying to call is not in scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   //do your startup/initializations here
});

 // This method should be available for you
 function showhideitems(itemID){
      if ($(itemID).css('display') == 'none')
      {
        $(itemID).show('slow'); 
      } else { 
        $(itemID).hide('slow');
      } 
  }
</script>
```

**EDIT - You can try this, but I wouldn't recommend it.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function showhideitems(itemID){
      if ($(itemID).css('display') == 'none') {
        $(itemID).show('slow'); 
      } else { 
        $(itemID).hide('slow');
      } 
  }


  $("#aID").click(function(){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    showhideitems('#players1');
                 });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/j8ML5/)

Comment: the problem with your edit version is that it would only work for 1 link. However, I've got 5 that show/hide a different div. How could a variable be passed through that to show/hide the correct div?

Comment: If you have different IDs and if it is possible to figure out the ID in the code, you can code it inside click method and pass that as a parameter to the showhideitems method. If you are talking about multiple links, you can give them each an id attribute and write multiple `$("#id_here").click(....`  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8ML5/1/)

Comment: Yeah I could work it around that way you're right. But I don't know what is the advantage of using that method instead of the onClick I initially used which was in some way simpler to edit if I decide to change my page code someday.

Comment: [here is a thread with some details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398760/whats-the-difference-between-using-jquerys-onclick-and-the-onclick-attribute).

Answer (score 2):

You defined `showhideitems()` inside another function.  That hides it from the global scope, so your link's `onclick` handler doesn't know how to find `showhideitems`.  Try removing `showhideitems` from the other function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showhideitems(itemID){
    if ($(itemID).css('display') == 'none')
    {
      $(itemID).show('slow'); 
    } else { 
      $(itemID).hide('slow');
    } 
  }
</script>
```