# Scope for page that is included using load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have an `index.php` and a `contact.php`.

`index.php` uses `load()` like so: `$("#content").load("contact.php");` and everything is great...

My problem is that on `contact.php`, there is a form, and I can't seem to get functions to run when the form is submitted.

index.php has jquery loaded. I've tried putting this function in and out of a ready tag:

```
function contact_submit(){
   alert('a');
}
```

on contact.php:

```
<form .....
   <input onclick="contact_submit();"  ....
```

I've been experimenting, and put the function on contact.php, but still no luck. I did notice that if I want to use jquery on contact.php I need to include jquery.js on that page (it doesn't steal it from index).

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong, or how I can have a function on index.php be used in the `load`ed contact.php? If you need more of my code please let me know...

**EDIT** Will I need to put my global function in a .js file and load them on all pages that will be used? I know it sounds like a basic question, but does using `load()` not re-use Javascript functions on my index page?

Comment: maybe `window.opener.[function]`? (guess here)

Comment: What's `ready tag`, I wonder? If you define this `contact_sumbit` function inside a function (any function), it's not visible in the global scope (used by that `onclick` code).

Comment: There is probably a javascript error message, please post that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to add an event listener and execute the code after all the DOM Elements have been loaded, provided there are no bugs in your php.

A few of these may be:

1. http://api.jquery.com/live/
2. http://api.jquery.com/on/
3. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

The first two apply to individual pages, and the third to DOM.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and let you know.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!!! So does anyone know when I should use the regular `.click()` and when I should use `.on('click'...`?

Comment: .click is the best to use(in my opinion), but I'll refer you to:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398760/whats-the-difference-between-using-jquerys-onclick-and-the-onclick-attribute. Remember to accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

The event isn't going to come along for the ride. You will need to add something on index.php or use jQuery's getScript method. If you put something on index.php, you'll just want to use jQuery's event delegation.

```
$('form').on('click','input',contact_submit);
```

Else, I'd recommend this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/