# Show/Hide a dropdown and button based on a checkbox in HTML and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, checkbox

Im trying to show/hide a dropdown list and button in HTML but having problems trying to get it to work. So this is the HTML setup:

```
<td valign="top">
    <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="switchBox" onClick="showHideForm(this,'extra')"> 
</td>
<div id="extra">
   <td valign="top"><form:select path="uSelectedSystemId" id="uSelectedSystemId"></form:select> </td>
   <td valign="top"><button type="button" id="fUndelete">Undelete</button</td>
</div>
```

and this is the function:

```
function showHideForm(box, id) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    elm.style.display = box.checked ? $('#uSelectedSystemId').hide() : $('#uSelectedSystemId').show();
    elm.style.display = box.checked ? $('#fUndelete').hide() : $('#fUndelete').show();
}
```

Nothing happens when I check the box. Any ideas on what im doing wrong? Also, are there any suggestions on how to hide the dropdown and button when the page first loads as at the moment it is showing (and I want them hidden).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bit of a random mix of jQuery and javascript there. If you gave your checkbox an ID you could simply do the following

```
$(function(){

    $('#uSelectedSystemId').hide();  //Hide the elements onload
    $('#fUndelete').hide();          //Hide the elements onload

    $('#checkboxID').click(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
              $('#uSelectedSystemId').show();
              $('#fUndelete').show();
          } else {
              $('#uSelectedSystemId').hide();
              $('#fUndelete').hide();
          }
    });
});
```

The line `$('#checkboxID')` could be changed to this `$('input[name="switchBox"]')` if you didn't want to give the checkbox an ID for whatever reason.

Below is a rework of your function
This will hide and show the DIV with the id of extra. The code above won't hide the div but
the two elements inside. This can be easily tweaked though

```
//Pure javascript version
function showHideForm(box, id) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    if(box.checked){
        elm.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        elm.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the change event over the click event. IIRC the order of those two events firing depends from browser to browser.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed, thanks! Only issue now is that the dropdown and button are displayed when the form first loads, but I want them to be hidden. Any idea what needs to be done to get that working?

Comment: @maloney either add a style attribute to the div or individual elements like so `style="display:none"` or add a class to the elements you want to hide onload like so `class="hidden"' and add the hidden styling to the class in the css file. or you could do add it to the jQuery block (PLEASE SEE EDIT ABOVE)

Comment: @maloney don't use the `$(function(){});` instead put the code in a method and call it from the onclick attribute I've posted an answer describing this

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy don't confuse the poor guy. The code i've shown at the beginning is better practice it keeps code cleaner and allows multiple onclick events please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398760/whats-the-difference-between-using-jquerys-onclick-and-the-onclick-attribute

Comment: @MarkWalters - i've tried this but it still remains shown: `<div style="display:none" id="extra" >` - is that the correct syntax?

Comment: Actually, i've done it - the `"display:none"` needed to be added to the parts I wanted to hide rather than just the `div`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

call the function upon onchange event of the checkbox

```
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="switchBox" onchange="showHideForm(this,'extra')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mix of jQuery and pure JavaScript,

```
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="switchBox" style="display:none" onClick="showHideForm()">
```

things should work like this jQuery:

```
function showHideForm() {
    if($('#checkboxID').is(':checked')){
        $('#uSelectedSystemId').hide();
        $('#fUndelete').hide();
    }else {
              $('#uSelectedSystemId').show();
              $('#fUndelete').show();
    }
}
```

pure js:

```
function showHideForm(){
    if(document.getElementById('checkboxID').checked){
        document.getElementById("uSelectedSystemId").style.display="none"
        document.getElementById("fUndelete").style.display="none"
    }else{
        document.getElementById("uSelectedSystemId").style.display="block"
        document.getElementById("fUndelete").style.display="block"
    }
}
```